# How do I get the most frequent uni-, bi-, tri-grams using shingles in Elasticsearch across all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lexical-analysis, n-gram

I am using the following field definition in my elasticsearch index:

```
"my_text" :{
  "type" : "string",
  "index" : "analyzed",
  "analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer",
  "term_vector": "with_positions",
  "term_statistics" : true      
}
```

where, `my_ngram_analyzer` is used to tokenize text into n-grams using shingles and is defined as:

```
    "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
        "filter" : {
            "nGram_filter": {
                "type": "shingle",
                "max_shingle_size": 5,
                "min_shingle_size": 2,
                "output_unigrams":"true"
            }
        },
        "analyzer" : {
            "my_ngram_analyzer" :{
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter" : [
                    "lowercase",
                    "nGram_filter"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I find the most frequent n-gram (n = 1 to 5) and its frequency across all documents ?
2. Is there a way to get total term frequency of an n-gram without querying for a document using the [termvector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-termvectors.html) API with term_statistics ?